# When Exchange receives a message, send notification to another address

Tags: email, exchange

I have an internal Exchange 2010 server that receives no outside email and sends no email outside.  I'd like to send a *notification* email to an outside email when a user receives a message on the internal Exchange server.

This message would simply say "A Message has been sent to your XYZ Email, go check it"

Theoretically, the AD would have an external email address associated with the user's AD account.  I'm hoping that a process could be triggered when an email is received on this Exchange server and I could take some type of action to look up the AD account for the recipient, grab the external email address and send a standard email to that user.

This would be a global rule for all Exchange accounts.

The problem is that I don't know where to start.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Weird setup but a few ideas come to mind (and yeah I know it's an old question):

Assuming you allow Activesync you could use OWA to setup text notifications, albeit per user.

The only other idea I came up with was clunky and would require at least allowing outbound mail to a single external pop3 account that would then interact with a public folder on Exchange.  If you want details on how that could work, let me know here, otherwise I won't waste paragraphs explaining the idea and clunky setup.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what cersion of Exchange you're running but this is not possible with Exchange 2003 as far as I know.

I'm not sure why you have things set up like you do but why not create Contacts for the external email addresses and set up the forwarding options on the mailbox enabled users to forward a copy of messages to the external contact?

Comment: Exchange 2010.  Forwarding the message isn't possible because of confidentiality of the messages within the internal-only system.

Comment: I've looked at Transport Rules and can't see a way to do what you need.

Comment: I've also looked at Outlook rules and can't see a way to do what you need.

Comment: In Outlook 2010, you can have a rule "perform a custom action" or "run a script". But I have not investigated on what those actions or scripts can do.

Comment: Thank you Joe.  After some creative thinking, how about a custom transport agent?  is it possible to write a script to be executed every time an email comes in?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with "sending notification" option, don't think it exists frankly. What there's an option for, is to forward and email to external SMTP address. It can be done easily by creating `external contact` and forward emails to it. You can as well hide it from the GAL after you done the forward, which will allow the users of the Exchange Organization to see only your internal mailbox.

Comment: Forwarding the message isn't possible because of confidentiality of the messages within the internal-only system.

Comment: Well, you can test creating a rule for each user, which will send a notification to external account. Not sure if it would be possible to create such a "wide" rule. You can try creating this on the outlook level of the account, if it will work - you probably copy this rule for every other user.

Answer (score 0):

Had a look at something like this for conflicts I interest email boxes.  Was never able to find a suitable transport rule that would work.

However we did have some success on using get-mailbox statistics in the exchange management shell on 2007.  Downside was mainly it never seemed like an elegant solution and for a high volume mail server it would be very unsuitable.  Don't have the exact script to hand but it would right the value for
Items to a file and then compare it later to see if the object had increased.  If yes then it sent an email.

As I say clunky but if you only had a few mailboxes on the server it may suffice.

Answer (score 0):

With transport rule, you can do this. But... it seems that it does not work with these kind of message. The rule works well with a regular email but when i try with a voicemail message the rule does not apply. I don't know why, probably because it is a kind of system message.